# comparison of Fixnum with Array failed (ArgumentError)

Tags: ruby, selenium, watir

When the script wants to increment progressbar value it gives me:

```
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ruby-progressbar-1.4.0/lib/ruby-progressbar/components
/progressable.rb:93:in `<=': comparison of Fixnum with Array failed (ArgumentError)
```

The Script is shown belove. I ftryed to find solution but no luck. Can Anyone help me with this?

```
korpusu_id = []
        container.divs(:class => "resItem") 
        .find_all { |div| div.span(:class => "theText", :text => /TestAuto/).exists? }
    .each do |korpuss|
        id = korpuss.span.parent.parent.attribute_value("id")
        id = id[-38..-1]
        korpusu_id.push(id)
    end


    puts ""
    puts "Tagad notiek nepieciešamo korpusu dzēšana..."
    progress = ProgressBar.create(:title => "Failu dzēšana:", :progress_mark => "|", :format => "%t [%B] %p%%", :total => korpusu_id)
    korpusu_id.each do |korp_id|
        @b.goto("#{@env}/CorpusMetadataEditor.aspx?id=#{korp_id}")
        @b.execute_script("window.confirm = function() {return true}")
        delete_poga = @b.link(:id, "ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lnkDeleteCorpora")
        if delete_poga.exists?
            delete_poga.click
        else
            puts "Korpuss\n#{@env}/CorpusMetadataEditor.aspx?id=#{korp_id}\nlietotājam #{lietotajs} nav pieejams rediģēšanai.\nTurpinu ar nākošo korpusu!\n---------------------------------------------"
            next
        end
        container.div(:class => "resItem").wait_until_present
        progress.increment
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the final solution for my problem. I changed:

```
progress = ProgressBar.create(:title => "Failu dzēšana:", :progress_mark => "|", :format => "%t [%B] %p%%", :total => korpusu_id.length)
```

and this worked for me.

*Sorry for spam...*